# Encountered few errors after starting project with flask run such as ModuleNotFoundError: No module named api

Tags: python

I have flask based python project that I run with flask run.
Full picture of errors:

```
 File "D:\ias\project_name\wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import app as application
  File "D:\ias\project_name\entity\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from api import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'
```

Below is my project's files structure and content of troubled files:

```
project_folder/
    entity/
       __init__.py
       api.py
    wsgi.py
    app.py
```

`__init__.py` contains this piece of code:

```
from api import *
```

`wsgi.py` contains:

```
from app import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

`app.py` contains:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some of the modifications to make it work better I suppose.

From:

```
project_folder/
    entity/
      __init__.py
      api.py
wsgi.py
app.py
```

To:

```
project_folder/
    entity/
      app/
        __init__.py # Import from app.api the blueprint, initialize the create_app() from here.
        api/
          __init__.py
          api.py
      wsgi.py
      app.py # Call the create_app() from app to initialize and then do app.run().
```

Comment: My bad, I changed the the wsgi and app location in description

Comment: The project structure, you have provided wont work correctly you will face further issues. You can follow the way I have suggested and please make use of create_app structure for your application. Example way: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/appfactories/#basic-factories and rest will follow my answer. Edit: The wsgi and app are moved within entity which acts a whole microservice.